# error in syncing project after upgrading Firebase to 9.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to use firebase in my project and it needs the latest version of dependencies inside .gradle file but when I set the version to latest which is 9.2.0 it doesn't and gives error but when I set it to previous version it works the previous version is 9.0.2 . This is my .gradle file :

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "naqibshayea.afghanbazaar"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes
        {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
   repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   }
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the error it shows :

```
Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.2.0
Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0
Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0
Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0
```

Comment: Sorry for dumb question.. Did you update the firebase SDK/library? Since it is finding 9.0.2 but fails to find 9.2.0, it seems that it is not updated.

Comment: yes it is updated I don't know why it is not working

Comment: did you add root level `build.gradle` file this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

1. Launch the and Android SDK manager
2. Update the Google Play services to the latest version, in this case to version **31**
3. Update the Google Repository to the latest version, in this case to version **29**

Then sync your project and the issue should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is an actual recent library release. So you must update Google Play Service and Google Repository to the last version. Please see this tutorial [How to update the IDE and tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html) by [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com).

Answer (score 0):

Update   Google Play services and Google Repository from Android Sdk Manager to **most recent** versions. In my case   Google Play services(33) and Google Repository(34).This solved the sync issue.